# Cypress spy not being called when VueJS component emits event

Tags: vue.js, cypress, sinon

I'm trying to follow the guide [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/vue/examples#Testing-Event-Handlers) to test an emitted event.

Given the following Vue SFC:

```
<script setup>
</script>

<template>
  <button data-testid="credits" @click="$emit('onCredits')">Click</button>
</template>
```

and the following Cypress test:

```
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing';

import Button from './Button.vue';

describe('<Button />', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    const pinia = createTestingPinia({
      createSpy: cy.spy(),
    });

    cy.mount(Button, {
      props: {
        onCredits: cy.spy().as('onCreditsSpy'),
      },
      global: {
        plugins: [pinia],
      },
    });

    cy.get('[data-testid=credits]').click();
    cy.get('@onCreditsSpy').should('have.been.called');
  });
});
```

My test is failing with

> expected onCreditsSpy to have been called at least once, but it was never called

It feels weird passing in the spy as a prop, have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1):

I solved such a situation with the last example within [Using Vue Test Utils](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/vue/examples#Using-Vue-Test-Utils).

In my case the PagerElement component uses the properties 'pages' for the total of pages to render and 'page' for the current page additional to the 'handleClick'-Event emitted once a page has been clicked:

```js
    cy.mount(PagerElement, {
      props: {
        pages: 5,
        page: 0
      }
    }).get('@vue')
```

Within the test I click on the third link that then emmits the Event:

```js
    cy.get('.pages router-link:nth-of-type(3)').click()
    cy.get('@vue').should(wrapper => {
      expect(wrapper.emitted('handleClick')).to.have.length
      expect(wrapper.emitted('handleClick')[0][0]).to.equal('3')
    })
```

First expectation was for handleClick to be emitted at all, the second one then checks the Parameters emitted (In my case the Page of the element clicked)

In order to have the Wrapper-element returned a custom mount-command has to be added instead of the default in your component.ts/component.js:

```js
    Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (...args) => {
      return mount(...args).then(({ wrapper }) => {
        return cy.wrap(wrapper).as('vue')
      })
    })
```